# Perl operator eqv is not working

Tags: perl, operator-keyword, equality

Below code is not working but I don't know why.

```
my $q = (1, 2) eqv (1, 3);
print "$q \n";
```

I'm using Perl v5.14. And also what is the difference between "eqv" and "==" ?

Comment: "eqv" is a new operator in perl6.

Comment: cf [Data::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Compare)

Comment: Perl 5 and Perl 6 are both great languages, but they are different languages. If you want to learn one or the other or both, please be sure you know which is being referred to in the tutorials, web pages, or answers that you read.

Comment: When writing Perl 5 programs always start them with `use strict` and `use warnings` until you know exactly why they are recommended.

Answer (score 4):

There is no operator like `eqv` in Perl5. I think you are looking for `eq` operator.

To see the difference between `eq` and `==` operator, see this:

[perl string compare with “eq” vs “==”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14046669/4248931)

[eq vs. ==](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=276023)

Read this for more information:

[What's the deal with all the different Perl 6 equality operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176343/4248931)

[Comparison of the Perl equality operators](http://www.dlugosz.com/Perl6/web/eqv.html)

Comment: Read the last link given in answer.